# How do I migrate a Database running on a local server to another machine

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-backups

I've built a relational database in SSMS 18 and populated it with some data. I am about to return my newly bought laptop where my database is currently running therefore I was wondering what is the easiest way to migrate the database (Tables, Data, Relationships....) to the new pc's local server.

I just want to make sure I have all the files I will need to restore the database backed up before I reset the pc before returning it

Comment: [backup / restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/back-up-and-restore-of-sql-server-databases?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

Use the built in backup tool to back up the database. This will create a back up of the entire database. You then copy the files created by the backup to the target machine and restore the database from the files created by the backup program.

```
1) Select the database you want to back up in SQL Server Management Studio on your left.
2) Right Click and select 'Tasks.'
3) Click on backup in the popup menu. 
4) Note where the backup files are going in the file system.
5) Run the backup
6) Copy the files from the backup to the target machine.
7) In the target machine start SQL Server Management Studio.
8) Select 'Databases.'
9) Right click and select Restore Databases/
10) Click on devices and select your physical backup files you copied in step 6.
11) Restore the database.
```